# Why would the bottom door hinge close before the other two?

Tags: doors, hinges

I have installed a door (not typical, somewhat makeshift for a theater window).

Closed [image: Closed]

Open [image: Open]

Open-Alt [image: Open-Alt]

I'm using wide throw hinges due to the clearances I will need.

The problem is that the bottom hinge closes fully before the other two hinges, preventing it from fully closing (and not bouncing back a little).

Bottom hinge closed:

[image: Bottom]

Middle hinge closed:

[image: Middle]

Top hinge closed:

[image: Top]

What would cause this?

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add a few pics to show us what you're dealing with.

Comment: @brhans Updated. 

I didn't have all the pictures available at the time of original posting.

Comment: If you don't want to redo the whole thing with more careful measurements, my suggestion -- I'm not a carpenter but I'm good at geometry, take it for what it's worth -- would be to loosen all the screws in the bottom hinge, and see if that's enough to let the door close fully. If so, then try to mark the position that the hinge comes to rest on the door and the jamb, and then see if you can adjust it to stay there.

Answer (score 1):

"Installing a door" is called hanging a door, and it's an advanced carpentry skill. So much that pretty much all doors installed today are of the pre hung type. Your problem can be caused by many things, but the root cause is that the hinges are not parallel, plumb, and on the same plane. Remove the door and make sure the door frame is square, plumb, and on the same plane as the wall. Then make sure both hinges are at the same depth on the frame.

Comment: The door doesn't have a "frame" perse. It's not typical (pictures added). 

I believe there are small variations on some of the measurements on the hinges though. Very small. 1/8" depending on how you squint.

Answer (score 0):

Small variations can add up.  You have to be precise to hang your own door.  Or use adjustable hinges.  There is a reason why they are popular.

---

I would remove one hinge temporarily (perhaps the middle one).  It will allow you to see if this is the problem.  And then redo it to suit.  Shift the hinge vertically by 5mm.